# MySQL Handling Null Values in --batch mode

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have a table where some values are null.

```
mysql> select * from temp ;
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| firstname | lastname | address1 | address2 | state |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| john      | wall     | NULL     | NULL     | CA    |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I select from this table from commandline with --batch table and write it to file I get something like this

```
mysql -u**** -p**** --batch temp_work -e "select * from temp" > temp.tab 

cat temp.tab 
firstname   lastname    address1    address2    state
john    wall    NULL    NULL    CA
```

Is there a way to force mysql to print those NULL as \N instead so that it will be handled in proper way when I try to load the data back.

I do know the option of `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` where null will be written as \N, but I want to find a work around for this problem for various reasons.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use ISNULL(myColumn, "with whatever value you want to replace null with ").
Hope this helps.

Comment: The MySQL **`ISNULL`** function takes a single argument, and returns a 0 or a 1.  I think you meant to refer to the MySQL **`IFNULL`** function, which does takes two arguments, and returns the value of the second argument if the first argument IS NULL.

Answer (score 1):

IFNULL and ISNULL are slow when you are working with huge database which may have multiple columns with null value. A workaround is to have a sed or perl replace "NULL" with "\N". Seems to work fast.

So command will look something like this:

mysql -u**** -p**** --batch temp_work -e "select * from temp" | sed s/NULL/\N/g; > temp.tab

Answer (score 0):

```
"select IFNULL(firstname,"\N"), IFNULL(lastname,"\N"), IFNULL(address2,"\N"),IFNULL(address2,"\N"),IFNULL(state,"\N"), from temp"
```

Comment: Maybe you could accompany your code with some text to explain it :) ?